# Popup notification and lock/turning on screen

Tags: android, android-screen

For my apps I'd like to give to the user a warning. I'd like to bypass the lockscreen (only if different from password/pin/pattern) and turn on the screen. I don't want to use wakelock or keyguard api because they are deprecated starting from API 17. I tried to use flags like `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD, FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` but it seems they work only for fullscreen activity, not for toast or dialog. Any ideas?